# Use `dplyr` to find the maximum, minimum and mean temperatures for each day

Tags: r, dplyr

"Use `dplyr` to find the maximum, minimum and mean temperatures for each day in January 2018.  Present the results in a table."

I am unsure where to use dplyr to do this, below is the data set first line.  Day is measured as an integer

```
"DAY" "HOUR" "MINUTE" "TEMP" "RH" "WINDSPD" "WINDIR" "GLOBAL" "UVA" "UVB" "VISIBLE" "RAIN" "PRESS"

1 0 0 11.5 79 2.5 346 -0.1 0 0.01 -1 0 1005
```

Comment: Probably, `df %>%
  group_by(DAY) %>%
  summarise(min_temp = min(TEMP, na.rm = TRUE), 
            max_temp = max(TEMP, na.rm = TRUE), 
            mean_temp = mean(TEMP, na.rm = TRUE))` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `summarise_at` and specify the column (or columns) of interest inside `vars` and apply the functions wrapped in `list`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(DAY) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(TEMP),  list(min, max, mean))
```